Eclipse crashes as soon as I try to do something (Ubuntu)
This morning I've installed Java SDK on my Ubuntu (version 23.10) machine, tried it with some classes writte in text editor and decided to download Eclipse.
However, after installing it from the Ubuntu "App Center" and starting it I noticed that as soon as I tried to write the main method to do the usual hello world print for testing, it crashed: it made me make the project, the package,the class; but as I wrote the dot in "System." it crashed generating a log file like "hs_err_pid4182.log".
I've tried installing other Eclipse versions (from the official site like 2023-09, 2023-03, 2024-03) but nothing and the same happens with different versions of Java.
Then I tried not to create my own project but to press on the "Build Hello World app" in the Eclipse menu (when you start it up) and it crashes...

Are you sure those versions of eclipse are compatible with JDK 23?

See https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.swt/issues/158

Anyways it's hard to be certain without seeing the error.

@aled They said Ubuntu 23.10, not JDK 23. JDK 23 will be released in September.

I missread. But which versions of Java were used? Basic information  ismissing in the question.
